# Python (TKinter) GUI wont display text

Tags: python, tkinter

The code:

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
root.title("Mood Control")
root.geometry("500x500")

label1 = Label(root, text="From 1-5 how would you rate your mood today? ", font=("arial",15, "bold"), fg="black").place(x=10, y=40)


def sad():
    photo = PhotoImage(file="happyturtle.gif")
    label = Label(image=photo).place(x=135, y=200)
    label.image = photo
    label.pack()

def happy():
    photo = PhotoImage(file="sadcat.gif")
    label = Label(image=photo).place(x=100, y=250)
    label.image = photo
    label.pack()
    label2 = labe



button1 = Button(root, text="1", width=3, height=3, bg="lightgrey", command=sad).place(x=20, y=100)
button2 = Button(root, text="2", width=3, height=3, bg="white", command=sad).place(x=60, y=100)
button3 = Button(root, text="3", width=3, height=3, bg="lightgrey", command=happy).place(x=100, y=100)
button4 = Button(root, text="4", width=3, height=3, bg="white", command=happy).place(x=140, y=100)
button5 = Button(root, text="5", width=3, height=3, bg="lightgrey", command=happy).place(x=180, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Essentially im trying to make a fun little app that controls your mood, you can never be too happy or sad. So if I were to press 1 or 2 it would display a pictyre of a happy turtle to cheer you up.
 if I were to press 3-5 it would show a picture of a sad cat to make sure you're not too happy. I have everything figured out but I have one problem, I would like to have text above the images once they are displayed, for example "You are
too happy, here's a pciture of a sad cat". But when I attempt to do this it never displays the text. I have attempted to do this like this:

def happy():

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="sadcat.gif")
label = Label(image=photo).place(x=100, y=250)
label.image = photo
label.pack()
label2 = Label(root, text="You are too happy, here's a picture of a sad cat", font=("arial",10, "bold"), fg="black").place(x=100, y=40)
# above line is what is supposed to display the text, it doesnt.
```

Also of I mouse over "label2" it says "local variable "label2" is not used". How do I fix this?

Any answers are appriciated

Comment: does 'label.image = photo' not give your errors?

Comment: label = Label(image=photo).place(x=100, y=250), in this line label is assigned the return from place(), which is not a label widget. Trying label.image after that line should cause errors. Try taking out label.image and label.pack() lines and see do you see the text.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the happy function.

```
def happy():
    photo = PhotoImage(file="sadcat.gif")
    label = Label(image=photo).place(x=100, y=250)
    label.image = photo
    label.pack()
    label2 = Label(root, text="You are too happy, here's a picture of a sad cat", font=("arial",10, "bold"), fg="black").place(x=100, y=40)
    # above line is what is supposed to display the text, it doesnt.
```

The line `label = Label(image=photo).place(x=100, y=250)` sets the label variable to the return from place(). The object returned by place will not have an image attribute so the line `label.image = photo`, will cause error. If you want a reference to the label try:

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="sadcat.gif")
label = Label(image=photo)

label.place(x=100, y=250)
```

Now `label.image = photo` will not cause error, but this line can be taken out as you set the image when you do `Label(image=photo)`. `label.pack()` should be removed as you are using the place geometry manager already.

Leaving:

```
def happy():
    photo = PhotoImage(file="sadcat.gif")
    label = Label(image=photo).place(x=100, y=250)
    label2 = Label(root, text="You are too happy, here's a picture of a sad cat", font=("arial",10, "bold"), fg="black").place(x=100, y=40)
    # above line is what is supposed to display the text, it doesnt.
```

Edit:

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
root.title("Mood Control")
root.geometry("500x500")

label1 = Label(root, text="From 1-5 how would you rate your mood today? ", font=("arial",15, "bold"), fg="black")
label1.place(x=10, y=40)


def sad():
    photo = PhotoImage(file="tenor1.gif")
    label = Label(root, image=photo)
    label.place(x=100, y=250)
    label.image = photo


def happy():
    label1['text'] = "You are too happy, here's a picture of a sad cat"
    photo = PhotoImage(file="tenor.gif")
    label = Label(root, image=photo)
    label.place(x=100, y=250)
    label.image = photo
    # above line is what is supposed to display the text, it doesnt.




button1 = Button(root, text="1", width=3, height=3, bg="lightgrey", command=sad).place(x=20, y=100)
button2 = Button(root, text="2", width=3, height=3, bg="white", command=sad).place(x=60, y=100)
button3 = Button(root, text="3", width=3, height=3, bg="lightgrey", command=happy).place(x=100, y=100)
button4 = Button(root, text="4", width=3, height=3, bg="white", command=happy).place(x=140, y=100)
button5 = Button(root, text="5", width=3, height=3, bg="lightgrey", command=happy).place(x=180, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer. The code that you put at the end of your answer displays the text, but now it doesn't display the image. adding label.pack() as the bottom line of the happy function makes both the image and text appear but it also causes an error although everything works. The error is "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'" . Any ideas to fix this? thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Try adding root to label = Label(root, image=photo).place(x=100, y=250), and the none type error is because label is still being set to what is returned from place.

Comment: May be wrong on the requirement for label.image =, added more code to the answer.

Comment: Also, have a look at examples using OOP.